# R: Add new rows to a dataframe when a condition is met and then repeat the final value

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with repeated measurements for individuals

```
ID    Day    Value
1      1     1
1      3     NA
1      4     3
1      5     5
```

After subjects hit a certain value (5 or 0.5) they disappear from the dataset. However, I want to add rows for those patients and repeat the last value until day 60

Expected output:

```
ID    Day    Value
1      1     1
1      3     NA
1      4     3
1      5     5
1      6     5
1      7     5
1      ...   5
1      60    5
```

There are many subjects and the same needs to happen to each of them, so
when value = 5, repeat 5 till day 60
when value = 0.5, repeat 0.5 till day 60

Some subjects hit the 5 or 0.5 after 1 day, others after 59 days, and everything in between. There are also a lot of missing values, and if they are before a subject hits either 5 or 0.5 they need to stay NA.

I have no clue how to do this, I've been looking online but couldnt find this question, apologies if it is a duplicate.

If anything is unclear, please let me know,
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Don't worry so much about duplicates- duplicates are *good*! They create a large set of different questions for the same problem- increasing visibility. Worry more about *reproducibility* - see in @G.Grothendieck 's answer for one way to create a good reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the reproducible data in the Note at the end where `nday` represents the day number up to which we want -- we use 7 here but you can change it to 60.  Create a function which performs the calculation for one ID.  Then apply it to each ID and rbind the results together. Note that if `mx` already equals `nday` then since there is no `else` leg on the `if`, the value of `more` will be NULL and `rbind` with a NULL just returns the data as desired. No packages are used.

```
add_data <- function(data) {
  mx = max(data$Day)
  more <- if (mx < nday) {
    with(data, data.frame(ID = ID[1], Day = seq(mx+1, nday), Value = tail(Value, 1)))
  }
  rbind(data, more)
}
do.call("rbind", by(DF, DF$ID, add_data))
```

giving:

```
    ID Day Value
1.1  1   1     1
1.2  1   3    NA
1.3  1   4     3
1.4  1   5     5
1.5  1   6     5
1.6  1   7     5
2.5  2   1     1
2.6  2   3    NA
2.7  2   4     3
2.8  2   5     5
2.1  2   6     5
2.2  2   7     5
```

### Note

```
DF <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:2, c(4, 4)), Day = c(1, 3, 4, 5), Value = c(1, NA, 3, 5))
nday <- 7 # number of days up to which we need; replace with 60
```

Comment: I am wondering if this problem might be a case for `while` ?

Comment: Also, I really am curious about your thoughts - do you think the code you suggest may possibly be growing an object?

Comment: @tjebo, No to both questions.